# Jinja pass variable to new flask route

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to accomplish having when the user puts keywords into the form.search it passes those keywords to the route as the variable.  But I have been unsuccessful in accomplishing this.

So far I have this as the bootstrap,

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method=post action={{ url_for('search', keywords=form.search) }}>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ render_field(form.search) }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
  </form>
```

Here is my flask route and form.

```
class SearchForm(Form):
    search = TextField('Search', [validators.Length(min=1)])


@app.route('/search/<keywords>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search(keywords):

    form=form
    return render_template('search.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by taking out the need for the  variable in the route.

```
@app.route('/search/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    form = SearchForm(request.form)
    keywords = form.search.data
    return
```